# Does C++ have comparison operator that specify a range of values? (like 'in' in E language)?

Tags: c++, comparison-operators

I need to write a condition that checks if an enum variable in range of values, like it can be done in E language:

```
enum EnumVariable {a, b, d, g, f, t, k, i};
if (EnumVariable in [ a, g, t, i]) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a better way in C++ than ask 4 times `if EnumVariable==a or EnumVariable==b` etc.?

Comment: You could also use `switch` without `break` between `a, g, t, i` for example.

Comment: @KirilKirov, I think that's the canonical answer, care to make it one?

Comment: @KirilKirov: indeed the most idiomatic answer, otherwise it would be a mess with non-intuitive operator overloading, template programming, and subset specification structures.

Comment: Actually, this might in fact be the fastest solution, since switches are often implemented as jump tables, leading to constant complexity while comparing each value is linear and the other approaches here logarithmical.

Comment: @filmor The only issue is how it scales, and the overhead of writing a new switch block for each set of values to be checked against.

Comment: @juanchopanza They are not nice to look at, but macros would solve the scalability issue.

Comment: @filmor the fastest solution is with bit fields (see my answer): I have encountered it many times when performance is an issue - comparison is just one assembler operation. However I agree that multiple `case` statements is the canonical solution. I'm not getting how a jump table lead to a constant complexity. Can you comment or give a reference?

Comment: @Sigismondo Have you checked this? If you look into the assembly of a switch statement generated by gcc you will see how well the compiler optimises switches. A jump table is actually the worst case here, where a relative jump is performed based on the value you are "switching". I doubt the bitmask solution (which is mostly evaluated at runtime) would match the performance, but I don't have any data on this (yet ;)).

Comment: @filmor +1 for the "yet" especially - I understand now! I have to try this on the raspberry too this evening... thank you and see you later ;) (but the mask is evaluated at compile-time. only the `&` at runtime... let's see.... mumble!)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<sub>It appeared, that several people liked my comment and asked to post it as an answer, so:</sub>

You can actually use `switch` for *integral* types without `break`-s between some values.

For example, your code could look like:

```
enum EnumVariable {a, b, d, g, f, t, k, i};
switch( EnumVariable )
{
case a:
case g:
case t:
case i:
    // do something
    break;
// handler other values
};
```

This would be very efficient, but would work for *integral* types only, and not for `std::string`, for example. For other types, you may try to use some of the other answers' suggestions.

It's a bit long for writing, but very, very efficient and does what you need.

Comment: or you could perform a cast/conversion if the type is not what you want (e.g. cast/convert string to char array)

Comment: @MatthewPigram Converting a string to char array wouldn't be of much use since `switch` would compare char arrays by pointer value, so different strings with the same content would compare differently.

Comment: @user4815162342 is it possible to overload an operator to fix that?

Comment: @MatthewPigram You could define conversion operators for your own classes (but not for `std::string`), but in general that just begs the question what to convert them to. The whole point of the C++ `switch` statement is utmost efficiency; this is why you only get to compare against compile-time constants, and integer ones at that. When testing for non-integral values, use another tool, such as a series of `if` tests or a container lookup.

Answer (score 21):

In C++11 a brief way to express this is by using the brace-init syntax to construct a set, and calling `std::set::count` to test if the element is present:

```
if (std::set<EnumVariable>{a, g, t, i}.count(myVariable))
  ...
```

A compilable example:

```
#include <set>

enum EnumVariable {a, b, d, g, f, t, k, i};

int main()
{
  EnumVariable x = t;
  if (std::set<EnumVariable>{a, g, t, i}.count(x)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Note about efficiency: since the question asked about a "comparison operator", the answer is written with the goal of providing a fairly readable and brief *single* expression that does not require a separate utility function. Since it builds a temporary `std::set`, it is not nearly as efficient as a `switch` statement, which is compiled into tests or jump tables by all relevant compilers.

Comment: It *could* be faster for large sets. The look-up is order log(N). One would have to measure, etc. etc.

Comment: @juanchopanza: if the `set` was created once and re-used then fair enough, but not a chance when each element is put in a temporary `set` as per this answer (at this time) - each elements needs a dynamic memory allocation and deallocation.

Comment: The issue is not only the allocation, but building the set takes time n*log(n), so you really want to have a lot more than 1 test to do on this set to make it worth it.

Comment: To be used into such a condition, I would rather have a `make_set` function to deduce the template parameter. It would be less verbose.

Comment: @TonyD Absolutely, the thing would have to be built once only.

Comment: @juanchopanza Large sets are unlikely for a set of enums literally listed in the source code, as is the case here. Even then, the compiler could also generate very efficient jump tables for large `switch` statements (and in fact many compilers are known to do exactly that).

Comment: @TonyD It just occurred to me that a mythical "sufficiently smart compiler" could note that the same set of constant members is being built every time, and make the temporary set global, or completely replace the whole `std::set(...).count()` with a jump table. At the time of this writing, I know of no compilers that do such analysis of code using STL containers.

Comment: It's indeed quick&dirty. If you wrap it to get nice semantics, using a sorted vector for the internals is a lot better. (Or, if `.size` is small enough, use a linear search)

Comment: @user4815162342 My comment referred to the last paragraph, which mentions `==` tests, not look-up tables. I take that to mean a linear search with comparisons, as in the example in my answer.

Comment: @user4815162342: it's not likely to happen either - your mythical compiler would also need to know that any calls (e.g. `malloc`, `sbrk`) didn't have needed side-effects, and they're not even in the translation unit.  Currently, the Standard doesn't grant any special permission to optimise away their calls (e.g. the way it does for Return Value Optimisation in 12.8/31).

Comment: @TonyD I was  of course joking, but do note that the compiler doesn't need to see calls to `malloc` at all, it could simply possess enough knowledge of the *interface* of `std::set` to know that its construction is side-effect free. To take a non-mythical example, gcc optimizes `fprintf(fp, "%s", bla)` to `fputs(bla, fp)` without the ability to prove that it is safe to do so by analyzing the libc sources.

Comment: @user4815162342: :-).  Agree that the compiler could special case this far more easily than it could support it through actual analysis, but it'd have a tough time making it general enough to apply to a useful amount of code while being specific enough to be practical for the compiler.

Comment: you can write a constexpr function if performance is a concern.

Comment: @bolov: you could, but not using a `std::set` anywhere, and not if `myVariable` is... ummm... variable.

Comment: why use `count` when you can use `find`? it does too much.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Because then it wouldn't fit into a single expression. Other answers, such as the one by [Tony D](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22039854/1600898), provide efficient code, but unfortunately requiring multiple expressions or utility functions. I haven't checked, but I also suspect that the overhead of `count` compared to `find` in a small set is unlikely to be measurable, especially next to the cost of creating an `std::set` in the first place.

Comment: @user4815162342: [Expressions can be nested, and they can contains declarations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Are you aware you're linking to a page describing GCC extensions to standard C?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: as `set`s can only have one element with a specific key, they never have to look past that first element and `count()` will perform as fast as find.  That's contrasts with using `count()` in a `multiset`, for example, where there's a small performance penalty.

Answer (score 17):

There is not the same, compact syntax, but you can use `std::find` with an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). For example,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

enum EnumVariable {a, b, d, g, f, t, k, i};

int main()
{
  EnumVariable e = k;
  auto vals = { a, g, t, i }; // std::initializer_list<EnumVariable>
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << (std::find(vals.begin(), vals.end(), e) != vals.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

This can easily be wrapper up in a helper function that takes the enum value, the list, and returns a `bool`. For example:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_in(T elem, std::initializer_list<T> range)
{
 for (T i : range)
    if (i == elem) return true;
 return false;

}
```

usage:

```
int main()
{
  EnumVariable ev = a;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << is_in(ev, {a, g, t, i}) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If the range is large and sorted, then `std::binary_search` may be an even better option than `std::find`. In such case, add `assert(std::is_sorted(range.begin(), range.end()));` as a requirement to `is_in`.

Answer (score 17):

this is often/usually accomplished using bit fields in an enum (clearly, up to the number of bits of an integral type (usually 32 bits), that is the default type at the base of an enum):

```
#include <iostream>

enum EnumVariable {
  a=0x0001, 
  b=0x0002, 
  d=0x0004, 
  g=0x0008, 
  f=0x0010, 
  t=0x0020, 
  k=0x0040, 
  i=0x0080
};

inline bool CheckMatch(EnumVariable var, EnumVariable mask) {
  return (var & mask) != 0;
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  EnumVariable mask = EnumVariable(a|g|t|i);
  EnumVariable x1 = b;
  EnumVariable x2 = g;

  cout << "x1: " << (CheckMatch(x1, mask) ? "match" : "no-match") << endl;
  cout << "x2: " << (CheckMatch(x2, mask) ? "match" : "no-match") << endl;

}
```

that shortly can be seen just as:

```
if ( x1 & (a|g|t|i) ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: +1 really good solution, don't know why this one is not accepted.

Answer (score 10):

Yet-another approach is to use a template to specify the list to match in, which for your `enum` case will presumably be known at compile time (otherwise even the `switch` approach is inapplicable).  This allows a notation like:

```
if (in<a, b, c, d, e, f>(x))
    ...
```

With optimisation enabled, this should be inlined and yield something equivalent to:

```
a == x || b == x || ...
```

Implemention below (also [ideone](http://ideone.com/sHNBbi)).  I've not played with variadic templates much, so suggestions welcome.  In particular, how to make it type-safe so given `enum E { E1 }; enum F { F1 };`, `in<E1>(F1)` won't compile (without limiting it to a specific `enum` type).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int First, int... Numbers>
inline bool in_impl(int n)
{
    return n == First || in_impl<Numbers...>(n);
}

template <>
inline bool in_impl<int(-1)>(int n)
{
    return false;
}

template <int... Numbers>
inline bool in(int n) 
{
    return in_impl<Numbers..., int(-1)>(n);
}

enum E { E1, E2, E3, E4 };

int main()
{
    std::cout << in<3, 5, 7, 9>(4) << '\n';
    std::cout << in<3, 5, 7, 9>(5) << '\n';
    std::cout << in<E2, E4>(E1) << '\n';
    std::cout << in<E2, E4>(E2) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
0
1
```

Comment: I'm surprised nobody else suggested using variadic templates, this method was the first thing to come to mind as I read through the question. Maybe that's just because I recently dove into using the template-heavy boost libraries and so the idea of using templates for a variety of purposes that people might not normally think of is fresh in my mind, though.

Comment: With more effort, it is possible to have logarithm search instead of linear one.

Comment: @JAB I was also surprised nobody posted before me... I was pretty slow getting it going too.

Comment: @Jarod42 Or, if the `enum` is restricted to bitflags as in [Sigismondo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22035686/138772), the operation would become a simple bitwise check rather than a search (assuming proper optimizations enabled). There could even be an auxiliary template to map non-bitflags enums to, say, `std::bitset`s bit fields and then perform the bit masking that way.

Comment: @Jarod42: true, though *very considerably* more effort - particularly if starting from only Standard libraries - do knock yourself out if you've got the time and inclination.  I suppose the compiler could detect that there are no side effects that short-circuit evaluation needs to protect against, and potentially optimise the above to something logarithmic too, but that's probably overly hopeful.

Comment: @JAB: when the enumerations are independent bit flags, direct use of bitwise operations is already very convenient, though often in C++ I rewrite the operators so the results don't decay to `int`s; a mix of such flags and bit-fields is just nasty... I've written macros for marking up enumerations with annotations about such things to guide generated serialisation/deserialisation routines, but it's ugly and rare enough that I'm not convinced it's worth getting into.

Comment: @TonyD: I mean *compile sort* the template argument and then do a binary search.

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, that's what I understood you to mean.

Comment: This is the best solution, since it doesn't involve hacks (named operators), doesn't require c++14, doesn't require integral types. And it's efficient and concise.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen It does require setting up a triple of utility functions and having them available. I'm not saying it invalidates the answer (I personally like it), but it's a relevant datapoint in determining "the best" solution. It is also the reason I don't believe it is possible to come up with an answer to this question that is clearly the best, one only gets to choose the tradeoff.

Answer (score 6):

It's absolutely not idiomatic, and probably to avoid, but the closest you can have (syntactically speaking) is to use [named operators](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/23179/15094). Named operators actually correspond to an abuse of operator overloading.

```
enum EnumVariable {a, b, d, g, f, t, k, i};

auto in = make_named_operator(
[](int i, std::initializer_list<EnumVariable> const& x) {
    return std::find(std::begin(x), std::end(x), i) != std::end(x);
});

auto vals = { a, g, t, i };
if (g <in> vals)
{
    std::cout << "It works!" << std::endl;
}
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4af6f8181cf64aa7) is a working example on Coliru.

---

If you use C++14 and polymorphic lambdas, you can make the above example more generic:

```
auto in = make_named_operator(
[](int i, auto const& x) {
    return std::find(std::begin(x), std::end(x), i) != std::end(x);
});
```

Comment: (Bit of an aside: the term "named operator" is [already in long-established use in GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/C_002b_002b) to refer to the alphabetic alternative tokens such as `and`, `or`, `not`, `xor_eq` etc..)

Comment: @TonyD Well, I did not create the name unfortunately, and I have no idea how I should call this construct then (besides "evil"). By the way, the link you provided is dead.