# Why do we need instantation of enum type in C?

Tags: c, types, enums, integer, instantiation

Let's say we have a `enum` declared outside the main function in a C code.

We can access the members of the `enum` inside the function without issue, and also assign it to variables of `int` data type.

But, there exists the concept *instantation* of `enum` type, i.e.,

Why is it required when using `enum` elements with `int` also does the task?

I declared this outside the main function:

```
enum months {Jan, Feb, Mar};
```

..and accessed it's member(s) using `int` inside the `main()` function

```
int main () {
         int m=Feb;
         printf("%d", m);
}
```

(prints `1` on screen)

But it's popular to create an instance of the `enum` type in the function where it's used:

```
int main () {
         enum months m=Feb;
         printf("%d", m);
}
```

(prints `1` on screen)

Why is this needed when you can use `int` itself?

Comment: useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646165/what-is-the-use-of-enums-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Instantiation* is the creation of an actual variable (an instance) of a particular type. In the example, you choose to either create a local instance of the `enum`erated type, `months`, or an instance of an `int` type, which knows nothing about the names of months, but can still hold the underlying number that `enum month` variables use to represent months.

While it's true that `enum`s are compiled to `int`s at runtime, `enum`s add a layer of abstraction to our source-code that makes it easier for humans to understand. We use `enum` types when dealing with a limited set of valid values, each representing a different meaning. Using them is all about being nice to your future self, because C gives you free rein to do all sorts of things that might hurt later; Ben Klemens (see *Resources*) describes C as "Punk Rock"!

Humans read source code more frequently than the compiler does, especially when you work in a team. Using `enum` types makes the code clearer, so that you and your colleagues can understand the *intent* of the code. The compiler doesn't know about what your code is intended to do - it just does as it's told - but it *really* matters to you, the developer.

When you make use of the type system, you're making it easier for developers to understand and maintain the code. Even solo developers benefit from this, because you soon forget the details of your implementation. You're doing a favor to the future-you, by giving yourself a clue, just like when you choose meaningful names for your variables and functions. Also, *enum*s tell the compiler which limited set of values are okay for variables of that type, thus giving it a chance to catch mistyped values at compile time, rather than failing at runtime.

### Caveats

With C, you still need to explicitly check for invalid values, eg. in a `switch` statement with a `default` clause, especially if you do any arithmetic on the `enum`.

Ben Klemens is not entirely uncritical of how C handles `enum` types, especially for cluttering the compiler's global namespace, thereby requiring longer, clunkier identifiers to avoid name clashes in larger programs.

### Resources

S. McConnell, Code complete: a practical handbook of software construction. Redmond, Wash: Microsoft Press, 1993.

B. Klemens, 21st century C, Second edition. Beijing ; Sebastopol, CA: O’Reilly Media, Inc, 2014.

Search terms **C "code quality"** or **C "best practice"**.

Also, definitely check out [Coding Standards for pure C (not C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262459/coding-standards-for-pure-c-not-c) on this site.

Comment: "While it's true that enums are compiled to ints at runtime" Not really true. _Enumerated types_, what you call "instances" (there's no such formal term in C) are of an implementation-defined type picked by the compiler depending on system and enumeration constant range needed. _Enumeration constants_ (the stuff inside `enum { ... }`) are however guaranteed to be of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

C has rather weak type safety overall, especially when it comes to enums as explained here: [How to create type safe enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043246/how-to-create-type-safe-enums) As shown in that link, enums are essentially just glorified integers, especially enumeration constants, `jan` `feb` etc which *are* actually guaranteed to be of type `int`.

but we *can* use `typedef enum` to achieve slightly better type safety. Namely when passing enums as pointers, because C has much stronger type safety for pointers than for plain integer types.

Example:

```c
typedef enum {Jan=1, Feb, Mar} months;

void print_month (const months* m)
{
  printf("%d\n", *m);
}

int main () {
    months m=Feb;
    print_month(&m); // ok

    int n=Feb;
    print_month(&n); // compiler error
}
```

(Make sure to compile as strict C with max warnings: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565))

Comment: Also the upcoming C23 standard supports some new features to improve enum type safety and integer ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `int`, then it's simply not `enum` type, it's like using `float` for `int`, you can use but it's less specific and loses information.

```
int main () {
         int m=Feb;
         printf("%d", m);
}
```

Here, type of `m` is `int`. In first line of `main` function, there is implicit casting involved from `enum months` to `int`. Wherever you will use `m` it will work as `int`.

```
int main () {
         enum months m=Feb;
         printf("%d", m);
}
```

While in second case, type is `enum months`. Casting happens when you call `printf`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `enum months` may or may not be compatible with `int` however. There is no casting here, implicit _conversion_ might happen when you call `printf`. This is because `printf` is a variadic function and therefore comes with something called "default argument promotion". `printf` has no intelligence regarding enums at all, they are simply treated as any integer type. And in case an enumerated type happens to correspond to a small integer type, it gets implicitly converted to `int` during "default argument promotion".